# jquery counter activate on viewport

Tags: jquery, counter, viewport

I have copied this counter code from https://bestjquery.com/tutorial/counter/demo155/
It works good, but when I put it at the bottom of page, it starts immediately and will finish counting before I scroll to view it.
I want it start counting when it appears on viewport.
Thank you.
This is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.counter-value').each(function() {
    $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
      Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
      duration: 3500,
      easing: 'swing',
      step: function(now) {
        $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.counter {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  width: 210px;
  padding: 0 0 25px;
  margin: 0 auto 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  position: relative;
}

.counter:before {
  content: "";
  background: #fff;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px 0;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: 50%;
}

.counter .counter-value {
  color: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #19bbd2, #2778ee);
  font-size: 38px;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 0 0 3px;
  margin: 0 0 25px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  display: block;
}

.counter h3 {
  color: #2778ee;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 900;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin: 0 0 25px;
}

.counter .counter-icon {
  color: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #19bbd2, #2778ee);
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 60px;
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.counter.purple .counter-value,
.counter.purple .counter-icon {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #8f70e7, #c452ef);
}

.counter.purple h3 {
  color: #c452ef;
}

.counter.magenta .counter-value,
.counter.magenta .counter-icon {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #e84a94, #ae379b);
}

.counter.magenta h3 {
  color: #ae379b;
}

.counter.yellow .counter-value,
.counter.yellow .counter-icon {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fecb4b, #e69814);
}

.counter.yellow h3 {
  color: #e69814;
}

@media screen and (max-width:990px) {
  .counter {
    margin-bottom: 45px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="counter">
        <span class="counter-value">343</span>
        <h3>Web Designing</h3>
        <div class="counter-icon">
          <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="counter purple">
        <span class="counter-value">324</span>
        <h3>Web Development</h3>
        <div class="counter-icon">
          <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below. Added description in comments.

1. Add additional class `pending` in your `span` with `class="counter-value"` like `<span class="counter-value pending">324</span>`. This `pending` class is used to check whether animation is already started or not. If its already started then we don't want to re-animate it.
2. Added new function `setAnimation()` in script.
3. Used `Utility Function` to check whether element is visible or not. Referenced from [How to check if element is visible after scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/how-to-check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling).
4. Add scroll event and call `setAnimation()` on scroll.

---

`setAnimation` function.

```
// create new function which will trigger your animation
function setAnimation() {
  // add additional class pending to your .counter-value element to check whether animation is pending or not
  // retrieve only pending elements and loop over it
  $('.counter-value.pending').each(function() {
    // check if element is in view and visible
    var isElementInView = Utils.isElementInView($(this), false);    
    if (isElementInView) {
      // if visible then remove class pending so it won't animate multiple times
      $(this).removeClass('pending');
      // initialize animation
      $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
      }, {
        duration: 3500,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function(now) {
          $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Try entire code below.
**Note** : Added `<div class="container" style="height:200px;"></div>` just for testing purpose only.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // call newly created function
  setAnimation();
});

// add scroll event to check for animation on scroll
$(document).scroll(function() {
  // call newly created function
  setAnimation();
});

// Create new function which will trigger your animation
function setAnimation() {
  // add additional class pending to your .counter-value element to check whether animation is pending or not
  // retrieve only pending elements and loop over it
  $('.counter-value.pending').each(function() {
    // check if element is in view and visible
    var isElementInView = Utils.isElementInView($(this), false);    
    if (isElementInView) {
      // if visible then remove class pending so it won't animate multiple times
      $(this).removeClass('pending');
      // initialize animation
      $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
      }, {
        duration: 3500,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function(now) {
          $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
      });
    }
  });
}

// Added util code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/how-to-check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling
function Utils() {

}

Utils.prototype = {
  constructor: Utils,
  isElementInView: function(element, fullyInView) {
    var pageTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var pageBottom = pageTop + $(window).height();
    var elementTop = $(element).offset().top;
    var elementBottom = elementTop + $(element).height();

    if (fullyInView === true) {
      return ((pageTop < elementTop) && (pageBottom > elementBottom));
    } else {
      return ((elementTop <= pageBottom) && (elementBottom >= pageTop));
    }
  }
};

var Utils = new Utils();
```

```css
.counter {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  width: 210px;
  padding: 0 0 25px;
  margin: 0 auto 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  position: relative;
}

.counter:before {
  content: "";
  background: #fff;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px 0;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: 50%;
}

.counter .counter-value {
  color: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #19bbd2, #2778ee);
  font-size: 38px;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 0 0 3px;
  margin: 0 0 25px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  display: block;
}

.counter h3 {
  color: #2778ee;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 900;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin: 0 0 25px;
}

.counter .counter-icon {
  color: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #19bbd2, #2778ee);
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 60px;
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.counter.purple .counter-value,
.counter.purple .counter-icon {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #8f70e7, #c452ef);
}

.counter.purple h3 {
  color: #c452ef;
}

.counter.magenta .counter-value,
.counter.magenta .counter-icon {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #e84a94, #ae379b);
}

.counter.magenta h3 {
  color: #ae379b;
}

.counter.yellow .counter-value,
.counter.yellow .counter-icon {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fecb4b, #e69814);
}

.counter.yellow h3 {
  color: #e69814;
}

@media screen and (max-width:990px) {
  .counter {
    margin-bottom: 45px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="height:200px;"></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="counter">
        <span class="counter-value pending">343</span>
        <h3>Web Designing</h3>
        <div class="counter-icon">
          <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="counter purple">
        <span class="counter-value pending">324</span>
        <h3>Web Development</h3>
        <div class="counter-icon">
          <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Karan, it works now. but what happens if I use 2 or more counters in different sections (top and bottom) of my page? I want to initialize each one when it is in view port (only one time)

Comment: This code will work. In case of top I've already called `setAnimation` from `$(document).ready(function() {`, so it will initialize at intended.

Comment: Yes, it works for duplicated counters too. Thank you.